# C# parallel and multithreading on single core cpu

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a application with C# and .net 4.5 that working on Intel core i5 system with windows 8.1, but when I publish the application and install on windows 7 SP1 that run on system with Intel Pentium 4 single core and single thread with .net 4.5.3 application not work completely.
the portion of code that I guess cause this problem used [Parallel.Foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

my application also using async await too.

Is this true that Parallel.Foreach and async await just work on multi thread processor?

how can I use this program on single core? if need to replace the code what should i use?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work "completely", what do you mean?

Comment: Parallel processing (or parallel programming) uses multithreading to maximize the use of multiple processors. See https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/concurrency-in-c/9781491906675/ch01.html for more discussions.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, program start with no error, some OpenFileDialog, Buttons and other function work, but when it's time to use parallel.foreach it does not go to next step, UI is not freezes.

Comment: @David, Does that mean Parallel programing not work on single thread processors?

Comment: @Execute.H - no, it does not mean that.  It means you're doing something that behaves differently in a single CPU architecture.. most likely this is a deadlock of some kind.  However, since you have not included any source code showing the problem, we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TPL, which Parallel.Foreach utilizes, works with threads rather than cores, it is up to the OS to schedule those threads. A single core processor would simply run the threads associated with the Parallel.Foreach code through the single core without issue.  Async/await methods on the other hand do not explicitly create additional threads, but rather run on the current synchronization context and use time on the thread only when the method is active.  Again, the single core CPU should handle async/await without issue.

That being said, you may be actually degrading performance by using Parallel.Foreach due to the additional overhead associated with thread creation/management.  If the code is not CPU bound, Parallel.Foreach is not really the best approach.

Comment: thanks, How can I diagnose this problem? I have no idea about that, the application run on my laptop and work correctly, but on my friend PC not work.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the application on your friend's PC?  Do you have any error logging set up within the application?  Have you checked the event viewer on the PC?

Comment: Can it be a deploying problem? I am used both VS publish and Visual Studio installer (Setup project).

Comment: What OS are you running the application on?  What versions of the .NET framework are installed on the machine?

Comment: Agree with all what you said except "If the code is not CPU bound, Parallel.Foreach is not really the best approach.If the code is not CPU bound, Parallel.Foreach is not really the best approach.". When a task such as an getting a URL takes too long, you might assign it to a separate thread and do something more productive with CPU.

Comment: on windows 8.1 and .net 4.5 work fine, but on windows 7 SP1 and .net 4.5 not working

Comment: @Tarik, TPL shines when handling CPU bound work, async/await shines when handling IO bound work, such as the scenario you mentioned.

Comment: @Execute.H, you may want to set up logging on your application to get a better idea of what is happening.  The issue you describe is difficult to diagnose without some feedback from the application.

Comment: @woogy, I create a windows 7 VM on vmware workstation with single core and single thread application not work completely so I add another core to vm and it work now on vm with 2 core. steal have problem with my friend Pentium 4.

Answer (score 2):

Good answer by @JTW, I would also add the following:

- If a system only has one processor, converting the program to use a multi-threaded implementation would not improve the the rate at which the data is processed. This is in case of a **CPU bound** program. E.g. numeric analysis of a particular data set. Also, the program won't throw exceptions.
- However, consider a program that is continuously interacting with the file system. This application is **IO** (input/output) **bound**, in that the rate at which it can work is determined by the performance of the file system. A multi-threaded solution would be able to perform processing at the times when one task was waiting for an input/output operation to complete.

PS. I know I joined this topic a year late, but heck hopes it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not bashed for digging this up, but I was just learning about Parallel.ForEach and wanted to know how it would behave on a single core machine.

For anyone who might also research this in the future, I'd say try and make use of the MaxDegreeOfParallelism Property of the ParallelOptions class that can be passed to the ForEach Method like so:

```
void DoSomethingParallel()
{
    ParallelOptions parOpts = new ParallelOptions();
    parOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

    object[] objs = new object[10];

    Parallel.ForEach(objs, parOpts, currObj =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the current object: {0}", currObj.ToString());
    });
}
```

Apologies if this does not solve the problem. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: You should look it up, I think this is the default.